# What is the chance that a zombie will drop armour in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the ratios for the drops of armour in Minecraft?

I don't want the wiki's answer because I have tried and the ratio is usually incorrect. I would like to know from someone who has actually done a test on this.

Comment: What have you tried? [Why is the wiki incorrect](http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif)?

Comment: It's 100% if you give the zombie the armour, AFAIK.

Comment: @fredley link in your comment is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rare drops occur 2.5% of the time. There are 6 possible rare drops from a zombie, 4 of which are armour, which I will assume have the same chance of happening. Therefore the percentage of zombies that will drop a piece of armour is **1.67%**, or a chance of 0.0167.

Comment: and still it depends on wether you actually kill the mob or if nature does. I had set up 3 skeleton spawners in a hc map and let them to 1 dropoff area. Letting them take only 1 hit to die. If i used a flint and steel to kill the masses of skeletons i would be lucky if i even got a single item. If i hit them with a sword or fists they would drop items pretty often. (the items cant burn because i take the fire away straight after.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Note that burning mobs is not good, as drops may fall in the flames and be destroyed.

Comment: as i said at the end of my comment. i light the mobs on fire and then remove the source. So the fire is gone even before a single mob starts to die.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that in 1.14 if a zombie turns intoo a dround the armor and weapons come off i found that out with a zombie/dround farm

Comment: This should probably be a comment. You gain the ability to comment at 50 reputation